# Return false on anchor $(document).on('click', '#selectorId', function () {}) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm clicking on an anchor tag and on click it validates the fields. If it validates properly than it returns true but if validation fails it should return false and stop going to href but unfortunately not working.

Tried `e.preventDefault()` as well but of no use.

Jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '#anchBillingAddress', function () {

    if ($("#chkSaveCard").prop("checked")) {
        if (ValidateFieldsOfSaveCardForm()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (ValidateFieldsOfPaymentForm()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
});
<a href="#billing-tab" id="anchBillingAddress" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Billing Address</a>
```

Comment: try `e.preventDefault()` along with `e. stopPropagation()`

Comment: Tried it. But still not working.

Comment: Can you post the solution which you tried?

Comment: $(document).on('click', '#anchBillingAddress', function (e) {
         
            if ($("#chkSaveCard").prop("checked")) {
                if (ValidateFieldsOfSaveCardForm()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (ValidateFieldsOfPaymentForm()) {
                    return true;

                }
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

Comment: Put the preventDefault and stopPropagation in the first line of the method. I think that is not executed cos of the return statement

Comment: Tried it but still not working. It does work for <button> but not for <a>

Comment: I think there is already an event added cos of `data-toggle="tab"` property.

Comment: But then why it's this code is working but the above code's not?

$('#anchBillingAddress').click(function () {

    if ($("#chkSaveCard").prop("checked")) {
        if (ValidateFieldsOfSaveCardForm()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (ValidateFieldsOfPaymentForm()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
});